# C++ thread that starts several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to do a program that has to run 2 tasks periodically.
That is, for example, run task 1 every 10 seconds, and run task 2 every 20 seconds.

What I am thinking is to create two threads, each one with a timer. Thread 1 launches a new thread with task 1 every 10 seconds. and Thread 2 launches a new thread with task 2 every 20 seconds.

My doubt is, how to launch a new task 1 if the previous task 1 hasn't finished?

```
while (true) 
{
    thread t1 (task1);
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    t1.join();
}
```

I was trying this, but this way it will only launch a new task 1 when the previous one finishes.

EDIT:

Basically I want to implement a task scheduler.
Run task1 every X seconds.
Run task2 every Y seconds.
I was thinking in something like this:

```
thread t1 (timer1);
thread t2 (timer2);


void timer1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        thread t (task1);
        t.detach()
        sleep(X);
    }

}
```

the same for timer2 and task2

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. What is `task1` actually?

Comment: Is that important? I haven't implemented task1 yet. But is just a simple function to compute some values and store in a database

Comment: Do you need to have two task1s running concurrently? Could you get away with one task1 thread where if task1 finishes early, the thread sleeps until time to run again otherwise loop around and re-execute?

Comment: It can happen that task1 takes more than X seconds to complete, so I need to start another task1 before the previous one finishes

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could create a `periodic_task` handler that is responsible for scheduling one task every `t` seconds.  And then you can launch a `periodic_task` with a specific function and time duration from anywhere you want to in your program.

Below I've sketched something out.  One valid choice is to detach the thread and let it run forever.  Another is to include cancellation to allow the parent thread to cancel/join.  I've included functionality to allow the latter (though you could still just detach/forget).

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class periodic_task
{
    std::chrono::seconds d_;
    std::function<void()> task_;
    std::mutex mut_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    bool cancel_{false};

public:
    periodic_task(std::function<void()> task, std::chrono::seconds s)
        : d_{s}
        , task_(std::move(task))
        {}

    void
    operator()()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mut_};
        auto until = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        while (true)
        {
            while (!cancel_ && std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < until)
                cv_.wait_until(lk, until);
            if (cancel_)
                return;
            lk.unlock();
            task_();
            lk.lock();
            until += d_;
        }
    }

    void cancel()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mut_};
        cancel_ = true;
        cv_.notify_one();
    }
};

void
short_task()
{
    std::cerr << "short\n";
}

void
long_task(int i, const std::string& message)
{
    std::cerr << "long " << message << ' ' << i << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    periodic_task task_short{short_task, 7s};
    periodic_task task_long{[](){long_task(5, "Hi");}, 13s};
    std::thread t1{std::ref(task_short)};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
    std::thread t2{std::ref(task_long)};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1min);
    task_short.cancel();
    task_long.cancel();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.
But this way it only starts one task one the previous one finishes. Right?

Comment: @jcmpoliveira:  Right.  If that's not what you want, perhaps you can modify this to do exactly what you want.  This answer shows how to use mutexes and condition_variables to establish any kind of communication between threads, no matter how complex.

Comment: But whats the point of the mutexes here?? 
Because thread t1 and t2 won't compete to access those resources. Right? t1 and t2 are running in two different objects of class periodic_task

Comment: @jcmpoliveira:  The mutex and condition_variable coordinate the communication with the main thread over the cancel state.  If you don't want that functionality, you can just use sleep_for/until instead.  Or conversely, if you want to create communication other than the cancel flag, you can use the mutex and condition_variable to do so.

Comment: Now I have another problem. the two function tasks (in your example short_task() and long_task() ) take a diferent number of arguments.
what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using `thread::join()` it, by definition, waits for the thread to finish. Instead, use `thread::detach` before sleeping, so it doesn't need to wait.

I'd suggest reading up on it http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/

Comment: I would not blindly recommend using `detach` because it can be very dangerous without very careful usage or additional synchronization to guarantee everything works correctly.

Comment: So how would you implement this?

Comment: @jcmpoliveira There are not enough details to provide an appropriate answer at this time.

Comment: Like James said, it can be dangerous. I'm not well versed in a general way of implementing it, but if each thread acts completely independent, then you simply `detach()` after constructing the thread.